# RANK function in/for Power Query

Tags: function, powerbi, powerquery, rank, m

Need `RANK` function in `Power Query`, Like in `Excel`, `SQL`, `DAX`...

The Best answers for now:

1. Built in [`Table.AddRankColumn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833369/6165594) function available since Jun-2022
2. [Solution with the best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72832216/6165594), at least at my test (~10% better then built `Table.AddRankColumn`).

Comment: @horseyride, A lot... In general - How to improve existing function? If decompose to smaller ones: 1) How to avoid doRename / unRename steps? 2) how to implement rank order support in a smart way (technicaly `>` should be replaced by `<`, but how to avoid code duplicating). 3) How to implement `Ties`  support (`DenseRank` in SQL Server)?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS recently released a rank function in M.

This satisfies all requirements like ties, dense rank etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addrankcolumn

Comment: that's great! 
Could you please provide a bit more documentation/examples for `comparisonCriteria`. Currently there is just one basic example: 
`...   {"Revenue", Order.Descending}, ... `
Does it support more rich syntax, like group of columns, expressions...

Comment: It is a list so you can supply multiple columns in there. Rank kinds are documented here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/rankkind-type

Comment: I see doc for rankkind, but not for comparisonCriteria...

Comment: comparison criteria is the same for any sort in PQ. There are examples here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-sort

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved if you question is answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
(tblSource as table, clmValues as text, optional RankColumnName as nullable text) =>
let    
    doRename = Table.RenameColumns(tblSource, {{clmValues , "XXXX"}}),    
    AddRank = Table.AddColumn(
        doRename,
        if RankColumnName = null  then "Rank"  else RankColumnName,
        each Table.RowCount(
            Table.SelectRows(doRename, (s)=> s[XXXX]>[XXXX])   // Magic ;)
        )+1,
        Int64.Type
    ),
    unRename = Table.RenameColumns(AddRank, {{"XXXX", clmValues}})
    
    // Regarding doRename, unRename steps - NB! it's superSmart, NOT superStupid (:
    // ... at least, I don't know how to avoid it ...
        
in
    unRename
```

How it works:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use as rank in PowerQuery.  It works on grouping instead of Table.RowCount iterated over each row, so my thought is it would be much faster for large data sets

```
(Source as table, RankColumnName as text, optional OutputName as nullable text) =>
let
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "RankIndex", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", RankColumnName, {{"data", each _, type table}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{RankColumnName, Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", if OutputName=null or OutputName="" then"Rank" else OutputName, 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index1",RankColumnName),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Index"), Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Index")), //next row optional
#"Sorted Rows2" = Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"RankIndex", Order.Ascending}})),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows2",{"RankIndex"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

if you need a SQL answer you should probably tag the question with that

Comment: Were you aware that this was recently released. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addrankcolumn