# Ranking of scores with ties in powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

Good day all,

I wish to rank the scores column such that the highest number take 1st position=1st.
The second largest number takes the second position etc.
Where there are ties ,give them same ranking order.say scores=140 occurring twice is placed 3rd.So in this case the scorers will have the same ranking

| Scores | B2 | B4 | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130 | A2 | A1 |  |
| 180 | B3 |  |  |
| 140 | A2 | 2 |  |
| 130 | A2 | A1 |  |
| 200 | A1 |  |  |
| 140 | A2 | 2 |  |

The challenge is how do I achieve this using powerquery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Table.AddRankColumn function with RankKind.Competition.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addrankcolumn

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQ2UFDSUXI0ApOGCkqxOkBBC7CgkzGIhIiYICkzgqrCptXIwADGxaU1FgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Scores = _t, B2 = _t, B4 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Scores", Int64.Type}, {"B2", type text}, {"B4", type text}}),
    Rank = Table.AddRankColumn(#"Changed Type","Rank",{"Scores", Order.Descending})
    
    in Rank
```

Comment: pls show me, a powerquery solution to this, i couldnt understand the documentation...Thank you

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit opaque. I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: Thank you @David,it seems Table.AddRankColumn is a new function? my excel workbook has none of this function

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: excel 2016 version

Comment: In that case, use the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830540/rank-function-in-for-power-query/72833369#72833369

Answer (score 0):

DAX option :

Modelling --> New Table

```
New Table =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    YourTableName,
    "Ranks", RANKX ( YourTableName, YourTableName[Scores ],, DESC, DENSE )
)
```

or simply Add New Column

```
Rank Column = RANKX(YourTableName
                        ,YourTableName[Scores ],,DESC,DENSE)
```